# ¿Expresión decimal para aceptar solo 3 enteros y tres decimales?

Tags: regex

Mi problemas es el siguiente tengo una expresión regular y lo que necesito es que me acepte tres números enteros y no mas pero en el caso de colocar un punto acepte tres decimales más y si los enteros son menos de 3 de igual manera solo acepte tres decimales.

la expresión que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
function filterFloat(evt,input){
                                    // Backspace = 8, Enter = 13, ‘0′ = 48, ‘9′ = 57, ‘.’ = 46, ‘-’ = 43
                                    var key = window.Event ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;    
                                    var chark = String.fromCharCode(key);
                                    var tempValue = input.value+chark;
                                    if(key >= 48 && key <= 57){
                                        if(filter(tempValue)=== false){
                                            return false;
                                        }else{       
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                          if(key == 8 || key == 13 || key == 0) {     
                                              return true;              
                                          }else if(key == 46){
                                                if(filter(tempValue)=== false){
                                                    return false;
                                                }else{       
                                                    return true;
                                                }
                                          }else{
                                              return false;
                                          }
                                    }
                                }
                                function filter(__val__){
                                    var preg = /^([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)/;   
                                    if(preg.test(__val__) === true){
                                        return true;
                                    }else{
                                       return false;
                                    }

                                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si lo entendí correctamente, en principio, según lo que yo interpreto de la pregunta,  estos números son válidos:

- 12, 123,1, 234, 23.23, ...

Y estos no válidos:

- 1234, 23.3456, 1234,5, ...

He probado con esta expresión y creo que cumple lo que necesitas: `/^([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{0,3})?)$/`

Un ejemplo de uso con node:

```
> let re = /^([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)$/
/^([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{0,3})?)$/
> re.test('2311')
false
> re.test('231')
true
> re.test('231.')
true
> re.test('231.1')
true
> re.test('231.12')
true
> re.test('231.1233')
false
> re.test('231.123')
true
> re.test('1.123')
true
```

**UPDATE:** Cambio para aceptar '123.' como valor válido

Comment: si entendiste bien pero no funciona porque al agregar 3 números enteros en el input  ya no acepta los tres decimales.

Comment: La expressón regular valida como correctos números como `'123.234'`, puedes verlo en el ejemplo que puse, es posible que el problema no sea la expresión regular

Comment: la función completa que estoy usando es:

Comment: añadelo a la pregunta original, será más fácil de leer

Comment: Listo anexado en la pregunta

Comment: OK @Yonathan20, he modificado mi respuesta, cambiar el último `{1,3}` por `{0,3}`

Comment: Gracias me salvaste

Comment: Por favor, marca la respouesta como "Aceptada" si te ha sido útil. Un placer poder ayudar :-)